# Live camera from android to C# server

Tags: c#, android

I need your help
I trying create client-server application. Client is android phone and server is PC (C#). I want trasfer live (as much as possible) camera preview. I think i must use in C# UDP and in java DatagramSocket. i added function for getting preview from camera and i trying send byte array to the server but it doesn't work. Maybe u have some solution for me, here is my code

```
 private Camera.PreviewCallback mPrevCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() 
    {
            public void onPreviewFrame( byte[] data, Camera Cam ) {
                    Log.e("CombineTestActivity", "Preview started");
                    Log.e("CombineTestActivity", "Data length = " 
                            + data.length );                   
                    try
                    {
                       InetAddress serverAddr = null;
                    try {
                        serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.102");
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, serverAddr, 9050);
                    updatetrack("Client: Sending '" + new String(data) + "'\n");
                    Log.e("Client ", "C: Sending");
                  try {
                        socket.send(packet);
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                  

            }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very, very complicated and not nearly as simple as it may present it self. Let me point out a few things that may help you:

- Read up on the difference in UDP vs TCP. Considering the amount of data you are sending I would recommend UDP. However, be aware that UDP will not make any attempt to recover any data that was lost in the transmission over the network.
- If I remmember correctly, one is little endian and the other is big endian. Considering your data is pure bytes, you will need to correct the byte order (correct me if I am wrong) that is being received. This is a whole topic in itself.
- Consider alternatives such as Node.js which wrap a lot of stuff for you so you don't have to deal with sockets where they cause the most trouble, at least on the server side. I haven't used Node.js before, but it seems like a library that works very well and saves you a lot of trouble. If you have never done socket programming before, it is living hell if you have no idea what you are doing; especially if you want to handle more than one connection.
- It basically comes down to the two two ends being happy and being able to talk to each other properly. I am not sure if you have a server already, but the biggest challenge will be for them to talk to each other properly. You have to let the server know exactly what to expect, especially if you want to send data that is other than just image data.

I hope this helps!